# Using ORDER BY with UNION and ALIASES

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some working SQL that I want to improve. The current SQL will pull through a list of all contacts linked to an account, including their relationship, and including an other option. This is being used in some scripting software that uses the code to display as a question within it, allowing users to select entries displayed to bring up further information.

This is working nicely, but I would ideally like for the Main tenant to pull through to the top, and the Other option at the bottom, and everything else listed alphabetically.

This is the current code:

```
SELECT [Relationship]+' - '+[Contact Name] AS DISPLAY , [Contact Name] AS  VALUE
FROM [Database]
WHERE ID = 'ID'
UNION
SELECT [Relationship]+' - '+[Contact Name] AS DISPLAY,  [Contact Name] AS VALUE
FROM [Database]
WHERE GroupID = 'GroupID' AND [Relationship] IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT 'Other' AS DISPLAY, 'Other' AS VALUE
```

At the moment, it will display information like:

```
DAUGHTER - Miss A C
HUSBAND - Mr V C
Other
SON - Mr G B
TENANT - Mrs S C
```

I want to list this as Tenant first, everything else, then Other last:

```
TENANT - Mrs S C
DAUGHTER - Miss A C
HUSBAND - Mr V C
SON - Mr G B
Other
```

I have tried using ORDER BY at the end of the code, but found this could only order alphabetically. I also tried to bracket off each statement and insert the ORDER BY function in there, but this did not work either.

Is anyone able to give me an idea of what I'm missing? The aliases and the UNION seem to be giving me issues, but I need these in order for the core code to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want results in a particular order, then use an explicit `ORDER BY`.  In SQL Server with a `UNION`/`UNION ALL` query, you can use a subquery and refer to the columns by their names:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ((SELECT [Relationship]+' - '+[Contact Name] AS DISPLAY , [Contact Name] AS VALUE
       FROM [Database]
       WHERE ID = 'ID'
      ) UNION
      (SELECT [Relationship]+' - '+[Contact Name] AS DISPLAY,  [Contact Name] AS VALUE
       FROM [Database]
       WHERE GroupID = 'GroupID' AND [Relationship] IS NOT NULL
      ) UNION
      (SELECT 'Other' AS DISPLAY, 'Other' AS VALUE
      )
     ) t
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN DISPLAY = 'TENANT' THEN 1
               WHEN DISPLAY = 'OTHER' THEN 3
               ELSE 2
          END);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Gordon. This does work, but only with UNION ALL, not UNION, so it is now bringing back duplicate values, but I think I know why. Is there any reason why this would work with UNION ALL and not UNION? Just curious to learn more about how this function works

Comment: @CraigJones . . . It should work with `UNION`.  I just prefer `UNION ALL`, unless there is an explicit reason to remove duplicates.

Comment: You're right, had mis-typed something my end, but it also helped me learn something about my code, so a happy accident! That works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE WHEN` statement to define the priority you want to use.

For instance use this `ORDER BY` clause at the end of your query :

```
ORDER BY CASE Relationship WHEN 'TENANT' THEN 0 WHEN 'Other' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
```

That way, we assign priority 0 when Relationship is TENANT, priority 2 when Relationship is Other and priority 1 for the rest and we use that priority to order the result set.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've tried to setup a case previously on this one, but it didn't work, but I will give this a go using this structure

Comment: You were right, with Gordon's structure below putting it all into one query was the final piece of the puzzle. All comments have been really helpful though, thank you for your time :)